# "Cannot set properties of null" error in project

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm a newbie with js/html, was nearing the completion of this small project when this error showed up after i added the "document.getElementById" tags.

This is the image which shows the error in the console

[image] and the following is the function that im writing and the object that it is referring.

```
for(const key1 in reservedSeats){
    if(reservedSeats.hasOwnProperty(key1)){

        const obj=reservedSeats[key1];
        console.log(obj.seat)//checking to see if it returns the seat number
    
        document.getElementById(obj.seat).className="r";
        document.getElementById(obj.seat).innerHTML='R';
    }
}
```

```
var reservedSeats = {
    record1: {
        seat: "b19",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    },
    record2: {
        seat: "b20",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    },
    record3: {
        seat: "b21",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    },
    record4: {
        seat: "b22",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    }
};
```

saw multiple stackof saying that the object needs to be above the "getelementbyid" tag, have done that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There's probably no element with the id you specified.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Without your code there is nothing we can do but point out the obvious - the error says your code could not find the element.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Most likely a duplicate: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare objects *before* you can use them (i.e. objects don't hoist).

```js
var reservedSeats = {
    record1: {
        seat: "b19",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    },
    record2: {
        seat: "b20",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    },
    record3: {
        seat: "b21",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    },
    record4: {
        seat: "b22",
        owner: {
            fname: "Joe",
            lname: "Smith"
        }
    }
};

for(const key1 in reservedSeats) {
        const obj=reservedSeats[key1]; 
        document.getElementById(obj.seat).className="r";
        document.getElementById(obj.seat).innerHTML='R';
}
```

```css
td {width:20px;height:20px;background-color:green}
.r {background-color:red}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td id="a19"></td><td id="a20"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="a21"></td><td id="a22"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="b19"></td><td id="b20"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="b21"></td><td id="b22"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="c19"></td><td id="c20"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="c21"></td><td id="c22"></td></tr>
</table>
```